# java webstart jnlp version issue

Tags: windows, java-web-start, jnlp, java-ws

I'm trying to launch a javaws jnlp with a bundled version of Java. It was working fine when I only had java 6 installed on the system but breaks when java 6 and 7 are concurrently installed.

One thing I noticed when launching in verbose mode was that even though the application launched in 1.6.0_23 (or at least I'm assuming it did based on the windows titlebar) javaw seems like it's launching java 7.

[image: verbose screenshot]

Comment: What's the question?  BTW - Recent changes seem to disallow using an earlier version of Java.  I guess Oracle got sick of fixing security bugs in the earlier versions.

Comment: The question was how to make it use earlier versions but I guess you say that's impossible now. Kind of sucks because when left to choose between not using some out of date java app (which requires an old version) or running an out of date java version system wide, a lot of corporations choose the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the installation paths are different for JRE's

JRE 1.7  PATH :   C:\Windows\System32\javaws.exe -localfile -J-Djnlp.application.href=http://host:port/your.jnlp "C:\Users\uraccount\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\xxx\xxxx

JRE 1.6 PATH :    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\javaws.exe -localfile "C:\Users\uraccount\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\xxx\xxxx"